# Proof problem in Haskell with take and drop

Tags: functional-programming, correctness-proof

Im learning Haskell and i want to prove

take m (drop n xs) = drop n (take (m+n) xs)

and

drop m (drop n xs) = drop (m+n) xs

Somebody can help me please? :)

Comment: Try a proof by induction.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Try formulating the claim in natural language -- that's be your question title.

Comment: Thank you :) Tried it again and i think my solution is correct :) Next time i will go more in detail with my question :)